# de-install ubuntu and install lubuntu with USB

Tags: usb, lubuntu, uninstall

I am trying to install lubuntu on my notebook (aspire one) as Ubuntu seems too heavy or is getting really slow. therefor I thought of installing lubuntu (or are there other suggestions?). Now I dont manage to de-install/remove Ubuntu completely.
Any ideas how?
I tried OS-uninstaller but then I get message that it is not the right kernel

Comment: have you saved / backupped all your important data from the notebooks hdd? Any other OSs running? You could simply format the harddrive if no important data is left on it. It also gives you a clean system. Already tried choosing another desktop manager? you can review http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/5-alternatives-unity-ubuntu-users-linux/ an see if Ubuntu gets any faster.

Answer (score 1):

If Ubuntu is the only OS that you have on the Laptop, just run the Lubuntu installation media, and when asked where to install Lubuntu, select "Use complete harddrive". Make sure to backup any data that you want to keep, as this will delete the whole drive. If Ubuntu is not the only operating system on the Laptop, choose the custom installation instead, delete the partition on which Ubuntu is currently installed (and possibly the swap partition) create (a) new partition(s) and install Lubuntu on them.

Comment: Since you also asked for alternatives: If you want to stay with ubuntu, you can try xubuntu, or maybe other desktop environments and window managers. Maybe have a look at this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-kinds-of-desktop-environments-and-shells-are-available .
If you want to, you can install ubuntu server (just a bash and the package management) and then install everything you need on your own. That way, you will get a streamlined system, but you will need some experience with linux/bash and/or be willing to do some reading.